# display goes black when inverted

Tags: xorg, display, xrandr

When I invert my display (`xrandr -o inverted`), the display goes black. This is in contrast to orienting the display to left (`xrandr -o left`), to right (`xrandr -o right`) or to normal (`xrandr -o normal`).

When I try to orient the display to normal from this black/inverted state (`xrandr -o normal`) directly, the display remains black. When I change to another virtual console (`Ctrl` `Alt` `F2`) and then change back (`Ctrl` `Alt` `F7`), the display appears again (inverted), but does not orient to normal on executing the command `xrandr -o normal`.

What's going on and how could this obstinate blackout behaviour be addressed?

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 with Unity.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved here

[Problem with xrandr rotation inverted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626221/problem-with-xrandr-rotation-inverted/631283#631283)

Hope it will work for you