# Problem with xrandr rotation inverted

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, xrandr, rotate-monitor

I have a lenovo x230t and have recently begun to retry with getting my screen rotation to work properly. I've been using the following: https://github.com/martin-ueding/thinkpad-scripts. But calling xrandr --output display --rotate inverted causes the display to go black. However calling --rotate left/right/normal all work properly. The display shows that it has the option for inverted, but obviously is not working as intended and I'm not sure how to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's a current bug in linux kernel

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1446979

The bug happens when switching between inverted and normal mode. A temporary solution is to rotate by 90° steps as follow

```
xrandr -o left && xrandr -o inverted
```

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-laptop-and-netbook-25/xrandr-o-inverted-causes-black-screen-on-lenovo-yoga-2-pro-gnome-3-14-2-a-4175533926/

This worked for me on dell inspiron 13. Hope it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

### Temporal fix

```
xrandr -o normal
```

### Constant fix

To file

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-quirks.conf
```

add lines

```
Section "Monitor"
        Option "Rotate" "normal"
EndSection
```

It fixes problem on

```
Lenovo-Yoga710-14ISK
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
GNOME Shell 3.36.1
```

More info:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr
- https://xorg-team.pages.debian.net/xorg/howto/use-xrandr.html
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103460/how-to-change-gnome-default-screen-rotation
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/xorg.conf.5.html
- [Where is the X.org config file? How do I configure X there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there)
- https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml#heading12